# From API 23 to 33 - I want to make activity transparent, but black screen issue

Tags: android

I want to make activity transparent, Using styles.xml it is working fine, but if I set style programatically, then black screen is coming.

I want to apply style based on condition.

I tried several ways and also read multiple Stackoverflow question as well as tried out:

```
 <style name="xxxxxxxxxx" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

 setTheme(R.style.xxxxxxxxxx)
     //   window.decorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```